# How to pass a key press back to parent?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2015

I have a MFC dialog and in the PreTranslateMessage method:

```
BOOL CAssignHistoryDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    BOOL    bNoDispatch, bDealtWith ;

    bDealtWith = FALSE ;

    if ( (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN || pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP || 
        pMsg->message == WM_CHAR) 
        && pMsg->wParam == VK_F5)
    {
        // Eat it.
        bNoDispatch = TRUE ;
        bDealtWith = TRUE ;
    }

    if (!bDealtWith)
        bNoDispatch = CSizingDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);

    return bNoDispatch ;
}
```

This is a modeless dialogue inside a parent object (dialogue actually).

How do I pass this VK_F5 keypress to the parent so that can process it too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably tried `SendMessage` and it didn't work. Try sending message asynchronously with `PostMessage`:

```
BOOL c_child_dialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_F5)
    {
        //***Edit: Find previous key state from lParam:
        //bits 30: The previous key state
        const BOOL repeat = pMsg->lParam & (1 << 30);
        if (!repeat)
            GetParent()->PostMessage(pMsg->message, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam);
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

BOOL c_parent_dialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_F5)
    {
        TRACE(L"parent-PreTranslateMessage-VK_F5\n");
        return TRUE;
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

That's assuming `GetParent()` return pointer to parent dialog. For example, if in parent dialog, the child was created as follows:

```
child.Create(IDD_CHILD, this);
```

However I think it is more reliable to create a parent function for `VK_F5` and other keys, then call it from child dialog.

Comment: Edit, added code to make sure previous key state was up, to avoid repeat messages